# Get returned $scope value from ng-model

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, firebase

How can I get a value from an object generated from an input using ng-model for use in my script rather than both the key and value?

So close to solving this problem now that extends from my previous question here [Get a value from input to use in controller Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/59077577?noredirect=1)

I've finally managed to prevent a single input value in a table (using ng-repeat) from displaying in each identical location for each row by using the following code:

```
<input data-ng-model="newEmail[$index]" type="text" id="newEmail"    maxlength="254" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" size="20" class="form-control" placeholder="{{user.email}}">
```

Basically, I need to get the value entered from the ng-model to use in my controller, which I'm currently using like this:

```
$scope.newEmail = {};

$scope.updateProfile = function (profile) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('New email is: ', $scope.newEmail);
    }, 1000);
};
```

The problem I'm getting is that it returns an object as **{ 1: 'whatever text is entered here' }** from the input box. I then simply can not seem to get the value out of the object to update a value in Firebase as it writes both the key and value to the Firebase location I'm trying to write to.

There must be a super simple way to get just the value out of the object that I'm missing?

Comment: Try to use array insead of object `$scope.newEmail = []`

Comment: Legend!!! It works and something so simple I should have tried array insteaf of object! Thank you - please post as answer and I shall accept!

Comment: I'm afraid to say it doesn't work after all :(. Seems as though if I click on the first row, enter a value, click my button, I will get the value. However, when I enter subsequent values in input boxes, it states empty slots..

Answer (score 0):

The input box doesn't return an object. It's because you're not assigning your `ng-model` just as `$scope.newEmail` but `$scope.newEmail[$index]` instead. That's why you get `{1: '...'}` when you get `$scope.newEmail` and it is correct.

I don't know what's you use case but why are you initialising `newEmail` as an object and not just:

```
$scope.newEmail = null
```

and then assigning it as:

```
ng-model="newEmail"
```

Comment: He use `$index` so he probably use `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've tried just $scope.newEmail = null and the returned value is empty when I log to the console. I've also tried 'newEmail' on it's own and still no luck. The reason I've had to initialise as an object is due to the above after trying this before (and again now) and also due to the fact I've got the input box pre-populated with a placeholder value from an array that holds the existing email from a user {{user.email}}.

Comment: Can you make a pinkr or jsfiddle so I can try it myself?